# Can I join each row of table1 to a unique row of table 2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was hoping to query in all the rows of a table that has its ids starting at some number, and update each row of the original table with a one to one of the second table.

For example:

```
normal
id | fk_test_id
----------------
1  | null
2  | null
3  | null

starts_after
id |
----
12 |
13 |
14 |
```

What UPDATE can I use to make `normal` look like this:

```
id | fk_test_id
----------------
1  | 12
2  | 13
3  | 14
```

I tried:

- `UPDATE normal SET fk_test_id = starts_after.id FROM starts_after;` which just joins on the first row of starts_after.
- `UPDATE normal SET fk_test_id = (SELECT id FROM starts_after ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1);` Where the subquery only executes once.
- Filtering the subquery by which fk_test_ids are already chosen, but it only executes on the pre-updated data.

Comment: The query you would need to do this would probably be overly complex.  You should step back and see where you took a wrong turn in terms of design.

Comment: Oh ok, it's not needed, i was just curious

Comment: The key problem is that you have no criterion to associate rows from one table with rows from the other. Different from a spreadsheet, a table in a relational database has no inherent ordering. Update a row and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you added record with specific order in to `starts_after` you can use below query:

```sql
update normal n
set fk_test_id = tmp.id
from (select id,
             row_number() over (order by id)
      from starts_after) tmp
where tmp.row_number = n.id;
```

I ordered by `id` from starts_after table (ASC) and create range of record with row num:

```
id | row_number
----------------
12  | 1
13  | 2
14  | 3
```

After that i join two table and update records